# For a given integer $k$, which of the following are false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For a given integer $k$, which of the following are false?

$(1)$ If $k($mod $72)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}$, then $k($ mod $9)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_9$

$(2)$ If $k($mod $72)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}$, then $k($ mod $8)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_8$

$(3)$ If $k($mod $8)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$, then $k($ mod $72)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}$

$(4)$ If $k($mod $9)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{9}$, then $k($ mod $72)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_{72}$

I am confused to proceed in any direction .Please help.

Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k$ is a unit modulo $n$ iff there exists a $b$ such that $kb \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. This implies that 
$$n | (kb-1)$$
Now suppose $d | n$. Then by transitive property of divisibility, we can claim that $d | (kb-1)$. So $kb \equiv 1 \pmod{d}$ as well. This means $k$ is a unit modulo $d$ as well.

For the converse, let us consider $3$. It is a unit in $\Bbb{Z}_8$ because $3^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$. Ask yourself: is $3$ a unit in $\Bbb{Z}_{72}$ or not?

Comment: No $3$ is not a unit in $Z_{72}$  since  $3$ and $72$ are not coprime.

Comment: @student Great. So hopefully now you can answer your queries.

Comment: @Anurag..Thank you,  so  going by your hint $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true,  $(3)$ and $(4)$ are false. For $(4)$ , if I take $k=10$, then $k$ is a unit in $Z_9$ but not in $Z_{72}$. Please confirm sir.

Comment: Sorry sir, I didn't understand the last part of your comment. If $k=10$, then $k($ mod $72)=10$ , which is not relatively prime to 72. So how can it be unit in $Z_{72}$?

Comment: @student You are right, I misunderstood your example. Actually you are using $k=10$ in two ways: $[10]_9=[1]_9$, whereas it will be simply $[10]_{72}$.

Comment: Ok sir, that was very helpful.